# What is the equivalent to os.system in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am writing a scala program in which I would to run a system command, reading the input from stdin, and writing it's output to stdout. (So, basically just like running the command in the shell."

In python, `os.system("command")` has this behavior. For instance, `os.system("python")` opens another Python REPL when run.

In Scala, running `"python" !!` seems to run the process and halt immediately. What is the easiest way to do the equivalent of `os.system` in Scala? I feel like this can probably be done with `scala.sys.process.ProcessIO`, but I haven't been able to find any clear examples anywhere of how this can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't need this to work in the Scala REPL, then `!<` should be all you need.

```
%> cat so.sc
import sys.process._
object Obj extends App {
  Seq("python3","-i").!<
}
%> scalac so.sc
%> scala Obj
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug 20 2019, 17:12:48) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = 4
>>> print('x: ' + str(x))
x: 4
>>> <CTL-D>
%>
```

Python isn't being invoked in a terminal/TTY environment so the `-i` option is needed to force it into interactive mode.